# Quarkus Application Crashing with IllegalStateException after Successful Email Authentication

Tags: java, authentication, quarkus

I'm implementing email-based authentication using Quarkus. I've added a login button and successfully authenticated the user, but the application crashes right after that.

This is my code:

```html
package org.quarkus.samples.petclinic.user;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import io.quarkus.qute.TemplateInstance;
import io.smallrye.common.annotation.Blocking;
import org.quarkus.samples.petclinic.system.TemplatesLocale;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Path("/users")
public class UserResource {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserResource.class);

    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    @Inject
    TemplatesLocale templates;

    @Context
    private HttpServletRequest req;

    @GET
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public TemplateInstance loginTemplate() {
        logger.info("Rendering login template");
        return templates.loginUserForm();
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/login")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    @Blocking
    public TemplateInstance loginUser(@BeanParam UserForm userForm, @Context HttpServletRequest req) {
        logger.info("Attempting to login user with email: {}", userForm.getEmail());

        boolean authenticated = userService.authenticateUser(userForm.getEmail(), userForm.getPassword());
        logger.info("Authentication status for user {}: {}", userForm.getEmail(), authenticated ? "Success" : "Failure");

        HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
        if (authenticated) {
            logger.info("Setting session attribute for authenticated user: {}", userForm.getEmail());
            session.setAttribute("authenticatedUser", userForm.getEmail());
            return templates.loginSuccess();
        } else {
            return templates.loginFailure();
        }
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/logout")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public TemplateInstance logout() {
        logger.info("Logging out and invalidating session");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        return templates.logoutSuccess();
    }
}
```

These are the logs I am getting right after I authenticate

```html
active, resteasy-reactive-jackson, resteasy-reactive-qute, security, servlet, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-jwt, vertx, webjars-locator]
2023-08-28 07:48:09,266 INFO  [org.qua.sam.pet.use.UserResource] (executor-thread-0) Rendering login template
2023-08-28 07:48:14,431 INFO  [org.qua.sam.pet.use.UserResource] (executor-thread-0) Attempting to login user with email: test@gmail.com
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.id as id1_4_,
        user0_.email as email2_4_,
        user0_.password_hash as password3_4_ 
    from
        users user0_ 
    where
        user0_.email=? limit ?
2023-08-28 07:48:15,122 INFO  [org.qua.sam.pet.use.UserResource] (executor-thread-0) Authentication status for user test@gmail.com: Success
2023-08-28 07:48:15,129 ERROR [org.qua.sam.pet.sys.ErrorExceptionMapper] (executor-thread-0) Internal application error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT000048: No request is currently active
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletRequestContext.requireCurrent(ServletRequestContext.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.ServletProducer.request(ServletProducer.java:18)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.ServletProducer_ProducerMethod_request_eaedc3e40b2e72a682c41b95c654df6e208065d2_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.ServletProducer_ProducerMethod_request_eaedc3e40b2e72a682c41b95c654df6e208065d2_Bean.create(Unknown Source)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.RequestContext.getIfActive(RequestContext.java:74)
    at io.quarkus.arc.impl.ClientProxies.getDelegate(ClientProxies.java:30)
    at javax.servlet.http.ServletProducer_ProducerMethod_request_eaedc3e40b2e72a682c41b95c654df6e208065d2_ClientProxy.arc$delegate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.ServletProducer_ProducerMethod_request_eaedc3e40b2e72a682c41b95c654df6e208065d2_ClientProxy.getSession(Unknown Source)
    at org.quarkus.samples.petclinic.user.UserResource.loginUser(UserResource.java:47)
    at org.quarkus.samples.petclinic.user.UserResource$quarkusrestinvoker$loginUser_5b42cda943fcade7331fac06cdf6a70c2c716e1a.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.server.handlers.InvocationHandler.handle(InvocationHandler.java:29)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.server.runtime.QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.invokeHandler(QuarkusResteasyReactiveRequestContext.java:114)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.common.core.AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.run(AbstractResteasyReactiveContext.java:145)
    at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$14.runWith(VertxCoreRecorder.java:576)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1478)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I've tried various fixes, but I can't figure out what's causing this error. It seems to occur when I try to set a session attribute after authenticating the user. Could anyone guide me on what I might be doing wrong or how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you have a sample application that behaves as you describe and that can be used to easily reproduce the problem?

Comment: I do on redhat openshift but I just modified the code to use jwt tokens instead and it is working so it's all good. thanks for the help